# Doesn't every nonempty tree on ${^k\omega} \times Y$ contain $\langle \emptyset, \emptyset, \dots, \emptyset \rangle$?

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

This is a very small issue that I have when reading the chapter on "Sharps and $\Sigma^1_3$ Sets" from Kanamori's "The Higher Infinite".

---

To give some context from the book:

> Suppose that $B \subseteq {^k(^\omega\omega)}$ is $\Sigma^1_2$. Taking $k = 1$ for simplicity, let $T$ be a tree on ${^2\omega} \times \omega$ such that for any $x \in {^\omega\omega}$,
>   $$B(x) \leftrightarrow \exists^1y(T_{\langle x,y \rangle} \text{ is well-founded}).$$
>   $T$ can be defined from a relation recursive in a real $(13.1)$, and by slightly altering that relation if necessary it can be assumed that    $\langle \emptyset, \emptyset, \emptyset \rangle \in T$.

This fact is stated again in different forms throughout the chapter.

---

Now I think by definition since any tree is downward-closed, if $T \not = \emptyset$ then we must have that $\langle \emptyset, \emptyset, \emptyset \rangle \in T$, no? And I don't get what changing the formula defining the tree has anything to do with this. I think I am missing some obvious and trivial point[because he mentions this in this chapter many times.] but I can't find it.

Comment: I've looked at the definitions and the only thing I can think of is that this comment corresponds to an older (and later modified) definition of _tree_. But chances are that I have the same confusion as you.

Comment: @PedroSanchezTerraf, It may be but aren't trees (in set theory) a universal thing? I have seen this exact definition a multiple of times in different books and papers. If you are aware of other definitions of trees that might cause that comment, I would be grateful if you could share. Also thanks for your time.

Comment: I believe you're right. The variants I'm referring to is about _trees on products_, where you might consider tuples of sequences of equal length, or sequences of tuples.

Comment: @PedroSanchezTerraf, I think I'm mega confused now(sorry for my naiveness). The definition here also involves tuples of sequences of equal length. So I think the variants you are pointing at might actually solve the problem since it's probable for someone like Kanamori to know of them and maybe (with a low chance) make an honest mistake of thinking that he was using another variant as his definition of a tree on $^k\omega \times Y$.